Question about the proof of Hartshorne II, Prop 5.12
This is a follow up of the question Here. Let me redescribe the context below:
Let $\varphi:S\rightarrow T$ be a morphism of graded rings. Let $M$ be a graded $S$-module and $N$ be a graded $T$-module. Let $f:U\rightarrow Proj(S)$ denote the induced morphism of schemes, where $U=\{P\in \operatorname{Proj}(T) : \varphi(S_+)\not\subset P\}$.
We have a canonical morphism
$$
\Psi\colon f^\ast(\widetilde{M})\to (M\otimes_S T)^{\sim}\vert_{U}.
$$
and
$$
\Phi\colon f_\ast(\widetilde{N}|_U)\to ({}_{S} N)^{\sim}.
$$
In Hartshorne's statements, he added the assumption that  $T$ is generated by $T_1$ as a $T_0$-algebra and $S$ is generated by $S_1$ as a $S_0$-algebra. Basically to check the above two were isomorphism, it suffice to check on the affine opens, specifically I mean the sets $D_+(f)$, where $f\in S_1$. One were able to show that
$$
f^\ast(\widetilde{M})|_{D_+(\varphi(f))}=(M_{(f)}\otimes_{S_{(f)}} T_{(\varphi(f))})^{\sim} \cong (M\otimes_S T)^{\sim}\vert_{D_+(\varphi(f))}
$$
and similarly
$$
f_\ast(\widetilde{N}|_{D_+(\varphi(f))}  )= f_\ast((N_{(\varphi(f))})^\sim ) \cong ({ }_{S_{(f)}} N_{(\varphi(f))})^\sim \cong  ({ }_{S_{(f)}} N_{(f)})^\sim \cong ({ }_S N)^\sim|_{D(f)} 
$$
Again, Hartshorne writes that, under the assumption that $T$ is generated by $T_1$ as a $T_0$-algebra and $S$ is generated by $S_1$ as a $S_0$-algebra, this map is an isomorphism. But the above isomorphisms does not seem to use the assumptions on $T$ at all.
I was wondering if the assumptions for $T_1$ not being finitely generated over $T_0$ by $T_1$ in both cases could be lifted.
Any helps would be appreciated.
